# Can you run PowerShell scripts in VSCode against different framework versions?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, powershell-4.0

I've written a script and I want to test it against PowerShell Framework 4.0, 5.0, and 5.1.  I have 5.1 currently installed and it works just fine but I want to verify it will work on 4.0 and 5.0.  Can I do this within VSCode?  If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't. You'll needs VM test rig with Win 7, 8 and 10. Or to test it on other PC with 4.0.

BTW PowerShell Framework is not correct fraise. PowerShell is part of Windows Management Framework.

Comment: I was afraid of that.  Thanks for the info.